# Detect backspace in UITextView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

How can I detect backspace in UITextView in Swift.

I have seen many solutions regarding UITextField but could not find any solution with regard to UITextView

Comment: It's the same as `UITextField`, whatever you do in `UITextField` to detect it you can also apply to `UITextView`

Answer (score 0):

`UITextViewDelegate` method will help you to detect backspace

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if text == "" && range.length > 0 { //Backspace


        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: This detects deletion, it does not really detect backspace. You can't be sure this operation is not done by selection and cut.

Comment: that is not correct at all; it is also `1` when the user _replaces_ a character in the 1 character long selected text, without even thinking about tapping the _backspace_ button (like e.g. select 1 character and replace it with a different one); and the user also can tap the _backspace_ button to delete more than 1 character (I can delete e.g. 5 at the same time and this concept will fail)... so altogether that is a wrong solution for the original problem in general – and it does not detect any deletion at all for sure.